# Why does piping input to a Bash function prevent assignment to a local nameref variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, variable, parameter

Given Bash 5.0.17 and the function

```
function assign_greeting {
  local -n output_var=$1
  output_var=$(cat)
}
```

why does `echo $GREETING` in

```
$ echo Hello | assign_greeting GREETING
$ echo $GREETING

$
```

print an empty line instead of `Hello`?  How might I change the function so that `GREETING` contains the contents of standard input?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 and probably many similar questions here.

Comment: Very helpful reference!  Thank you!